# How Can I check Property file path is set properly or not

Tags: java

I have a the following code.

```
public class PropertyReader {

    private static Properties propsPath = new Properties();
    private static Properties propsConf = new Properties();
    private static PropertyReader instance = new PropertyReader();

    private PropertyReader() {

        readConfProperty();
    }

    private void readConfProperty() throws RuntimeException {

        try {
            String path = "";

            if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Linux")) {
                //path = System.getProperty("catalina.home") + "conf/businessportal.properties";
                path = System.getProperty("/busDir/src/main/resources/businessportal.properties");
            } else {
               // path = System.getProperty("catalina.home") + "\\conf\\businessportal.properties";
                path = System.getProperty("/busDir/src/main/resources/businessportal.properties");
            }

            Reader reader = new FileReader(path);
            propsConf.load(reader);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How Can I check if the property file path is set properly and can access the data from it?

Comment: I'd say you check whether that file exists or not. That doesn't tell you whether the path is correct or the file is missing or inaccessible though. Besides that, passing a path as the property key is most likely the wrong way to go.

Comment: `File f = new File(path);
if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
    // your further code will be here 
}`

Comment: I believe it's not linked to spring boot. Please read [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: the usage of `System.getProperty` looks weird. 1) the argument must be a key 2) which must exists in the global system properties. I'm pretty sure that none of these requirements hold in your case .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to quite understand how system properties work, here is shot explanation before answering your question:

System properties are used to pass values to a JVM on startup or set them at runtime, those values can be retrieved using the [System#getProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-) method by passing it the associated name when the JVM is started or when set at runtime.

1- passing a system property on JVM start

```
java -DmyVar=foo -cp myApp.jar pack.age.MyApp bar bat
```

with this example you can retrieve `myVar` using

```
String myVar = System.getProperty("myVar");
```

After this call the variable `myVar` will have the value `foo`. `bar` and `bat` cannot be retrieved this way, those are the arguments to your application and appear in the order you passed them in the arguments array of your main method.

2 - setting system property at runtime

```
System.setProperty("myVar", "foo")
```

and later using the same call as before you can retrieve the value again.

Now to answer your question:

1- The call you have in your active code are not correct, since `/busDir/src/main/resources/businessportal.properties` seems to be the value you are willing to get and not the name you defined that will be used in your application to find it.

You should pass the value using something like this and as shown above by setting `-D` param when starting your application:

```
-Dbusinessportal.config.path=/busDir/src/main/resources/businessportal.properties
```

and then retrieve it in your method with

```
String path = System.getProperty("businessportal.config.path");
```

at this point you will have a String containing the path of your config file and you can proceed with checking its existence like this:

```
private void readConProperty() throws IOException {
    String strPath = System.getProperty("businessportal.config.path");
    if (null == strPath) {
        throw new RuntimeException("property businessportal.config.path not defined");
    }

    try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(strPath))) {
        propsConf.load(is);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String
            .format("Error while loading config from %s", strPath), e);
    }
}
```

2- You don't need to check for which os is the application actually running on in order to choosing the correct file separator, because first, when you application is started you already know this an can pass the correct file path, and second the java Filesystem APIs handle this under the hood for you and can work with `\` and `/` on every environment as long as the paths are cross platform compatible, which is the case for most relative paths and windows absolute paths if omitting the drive letter and you application is started on the same drive. So you cannot use something like `C:\\conf\businessportal.properties` on a unix system because obviously it it contains a drive letter which is typical for windows hosts only.

3- Last, I see that your properties file is placed under resources in your source code. You will not be able to load it from the file system directly because when your application is packaged the path `src/main/resources` will not exist and everything there willl be packages into you application's archive and will be present on you application's classpath. You will then need to load it using [Class#getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) and pass it the resource name like this:

```
private void readConProperty() {
    String resourceName = "/businessportal.properties";
    try (InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(resourceName)) {
        if (null == is) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String
                .format("Resource %s is not available", resourceName));
        }
        propsConf.load(is);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String
            .format("Error while loading config from %s", resourceName), e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful explanation now i got a clear idea. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Shozab glad I could help, you may then want to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/191550) and maybe [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it aswell ;-)